# How to create Avro schema for Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Float>>?

Tags: java, serialization, avro

The documentation of map of map is not very clear. I'm trying to serialize such an object(Map>) to Avro, how can I achieve that.

```
{"namespace": "example",
 "type": "map",
 "name": "Map",
 "keys": "int",
 "values": {
  "type":"map",
  "keys":"int",
  "values":"float" 
 }
}
```

Comment: @Alex A. Could you help me on this hint, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own solution:

```
{"namespace": "Schema",
  "name":"PvMap",
  "type":"record",
  "fields":[
  {"name": "TradeId", "type": "int"},
    { "name": "Tmap",
      "type":{
      "type":"map",
      "values":"float"}
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a map using int as key, right? It's not possible in avro I think.. did you manually convert to str?

Answer (score 0):

That field should be something like:

```
{
    "type": "map",
    "values": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": "float"
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. The outer map's type is set to "map", and values specifies the schema of the inner map.
2. The inner map's type is also set to "map", and values specifies the value type of the inner map as "float".
3. According to the Avro map schema rule, the key type is not defined and is specified when using the map in the code.